# How to dynamically set background color in IOS?

Tags: ios

I need to set background color in iOS using string value.It should be done by dynamically. How is it possible?

Comment: For what are you trying to set the background color and string like what ?

Comment: What will be the string looks like? Will it be a color name or color code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myColors = @[@"redColor", @"greenColor", @"blueColor", @"yellowColor",@"blackColor",@"cyanColor",@"magentaColor",@"purpleColor",@"grayColor"]; // NSArray contains value//   
    int a = arc4random() % 9;  //select random value//



  SEL abc = NSSelectorFromString([myColors objectAtIndex:a]);
          [_canvas setBackgroundColor:[UIColor performSelector:abc]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the String value and assign the color.

```
if([colorString isEqualToString:@"Red"])
{
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Comment: it's possible but how to check all colors

Comment: That'll only be done when the asker tells us what type of String it is, what it holds.

Comment: From color name how user can visualize how it will look if there are many colors. I think you should user color palette for the same.

Answer (score 1):

The following code block sets random background color to UILabel.

```
    NSMutableArray *colorArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[@"redColor",@"greenColor",@"blueColor"]];

    NSInteger randomNumber = arc4random() % 3;

    NSLog(@"colorArray : %@ randNum : %d",[colorArray description],randomNumber);

    SEL setRandomColor = NSSelectorFromString([colorArray objectAtIndex:randomNumber]);

    [testLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor performSelector:setRandomColor]];
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1.Get the String Colour from the user

2.Convert the string to a specific format

3.Use If conditon or Switch Case to check the  the string and Change the background using the above code given by **Objective-J**

have a look at the UIColor class provided in the below link

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not you provide the color pallete for the color choose.

Or

you can show the text Red in red color And then if user selected the Red color then get the pixel color of the text and then use that color.

or

simply use the for loop as @Objective-J is said